# Wrapping a file on my web server

Tags: php, android, mysql, download, wrapper

I'm currently researching this as we speak.  Putting this question here hoping to see some awesome insights.  Here's my question:

I am developing an android application that downloads files from my web server to be displayed in the app, and available for offline use.

If my app goes to https://www.mydomain.com/abc/xyz.png to download the file, how can I make that same url not publicly available? i.e. if you type https://www.mydomain.com/abc/xyz.png into your browser address bar, you will be taken somewhere other than the png file.

I think I need some kind of wrapper here, but I'm new to all of this and trying to learn fast.

Any help is appreciated.

For what it's worth, I will be using a mySql database with either workbench 6.0 or phpMyAdmin.

***EDIT***

In response to the first two responses:

So my code here in my android app where I download the file and save it to internal storage that looks like this (where base path gets me to the web directory of the file):

```
url = new URL(basePath + fileName);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

outFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

would change to say:

```
url = new URL(basePath + "download_file.php" + "?key=hardcodedkey&file=" + fileName);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

outFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1.) Not great-> .htaccess to restrict certain referrers, all but Android for example.

2.) Greater -> Use a PHP file to output the image if GET var is the same as the pass. e.g.

```
if (isset($_GET["pass"]) && $_GET["pass"]=="8h932mgks984jsolm9sjt4ms") {
    header('Content-type:image/png');
    include('/path/to/thePngFile.png');
} else die("nothing to see here..");
```

Comment: this seems to make sense.  Very helpful Thank you.  Please read my EDIT for a little follow up

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be calling a php script with a certain key as secret parameter and the image or file you want to download.

```
www.myweb.com/myfunction.php?pass=secretPassword&file=image.png
```

This key will be harcoded in the call from your application.

Then you could just check if the password is the one you expect with something like:

```
//hardcoded hashed pass with sha1, for example.
$myHashedPass = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef';

if(sha1($_GET['pass']) != $myHashedPass){
    die();
}

//download of file...
```

Inside the PHP application you can start the download or not depending on the password.

Comment: this seems to make sense.  Very helpful.  Thank you.  Please read my EDIT for a little follow up.

Comment: @user2581858 I don't see your edit. Did you deleted it? And, if it was helpful you can mark it as valid :)

Comment: Just changed the edit around for a few minutes.  It should be good now

Comment: ya, nevermind about my edit.  Lol.  It's pretty much exactly what you said.  Thanks again.